# How to change the style of image with a event in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui

How to change the style of image with a event in swiftui?
for example :change the image border color when I click a button, and the image is identified by name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo

```
struct DemoImageBorder: View {
    @State private var highlighted = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Highlight") { self.highlighted.toggle() }
            Divider()
            Image("some_name_here")
                .border(self.highlighted ? Color.red : Color.clear)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this, change the color border just for the desired image name:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var borderColor = Color.blue
@State var imageName = "xyz"

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            self.borderColor = Color.red
            self.imageName = "person.3"
        }){
            Text("Change Image border")
        }
        Image(systemName: "person")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .border(self.imageName == "person" ? borderColor : Color.blue)
        Image(systemName: "person.3")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .border(self.imageName == "person.3" ? borderColor : Color.blue)
    }
}
}
```